I got hacked on metamask today
Today I got hacked on meta mask: transaction hash
0xed8a4d46550431225fd2aab3bbd79ef9b4d55a31e8d2f4676d77004f658cbb84
somebody sent my eth from my adress
0xed8a4d46550431225fd2aab3bbd79ef9b4d55a31e8d2f4676d77004f658cbb84
to
0x9942D165B9DfC850E0eC303E7D0Ce116A3c57979
How can I contact the hacker? Resp. send him a message?

It is quite unlikely they will respond. But they have the most chance of being curious enough to view a message sent to their address as calldata:
You would want to

Convert your text message to hex
Use it as the data field for your transaction.

In your web browser to initiate through metamask it would look like:

While connected to a website with the address you want to send from
Right click the page and select Inspect
Click Console

To keep it simple and to keep the code readable, we'll use a website to convert the message to hex. But there are many ways to do this in code:

https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/ascii-text-to-hex-converter

Oi, you lazy waste of space. in hex would be:

0x4f692c20796f75206c617a79207761737465206f662073706163652e

In the console window enter something similar to the below, changing the message and addresses, then click enter.
Metamask will open with the options to sign.
In your browser console:
const calldata = "0x4f692c20796f75206c617a79207761737465206f662073706163652e"

const txParams = {
  from: <your address>,
  to: <scammers address>,
  value: 0,
  data: calldata
};

window.ethereum.request({
    method: "eth_sendTransaction",
    params: [txParams]
})

Example sending hello to and from an address on a testnet.

Console view:


How it looks on a block explorer:

Transaction view (utf-8 option):


Account view:




that's really cool !

It is cool, and it's really nice that the explorers support it, will often see early stage negotiations after the big hacks go back and forth like that. A team saying keep 10% but return the rest and we won't come after you, or a hacker basking in their 15 minutes.

To recover crypto from a compromised account, follow these steps:

Install MetaMask on another browser or profile. For mobile, use a second device to create a new instance.
Create a new MetaMask wallet on the new device.
Write down the Secret Recovery Phrase and store it securely.
Go back to the compromised account and transfer any remaining funds to the new account. If there is a sweeper script, don't send in additional tokens for gas.
Discontinue using the old wallet and any accounts associated with the compromised Secret Recovery Phrase.

Metamask accounts don't allow hacked users to recover their crypto due to their decentralized platform. All user funds and data are stored on the user's device, not the MetaMask server.
